# Counterexample: Convergence in probability does not imply convergence in sample mean

Tags: probability-theory

Consider the random variable $X_n$ defined by $X_n = 2^n$ with probability $\frac{1}{n}$ and $0$ else, for each $n >0 $. It's easy to show that $X_n$ converges to $0$ in probability. How do we show that $S_n / n $, the sample mean, fail to converge to $0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume (but it definitely must be stated!) that the $X_n$ are supposed to be independent.  Hint: use one of the Borel-Cantelli lemmas.